# Es obligatorio tener un dispositivo iOS para desplegar en App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Actualmente tengo el siguiente error, cuando trato de generar mi aplicación con XCode 12:

> Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered
> in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device
> to have Xcode register it.

Y SI NO HE ENTENDIDO MAL, para crear el "provisioning profile" en mi cuenta de App Store, se requiere tener un dispositivo iOS (iPhone/iPad), y sin ese tipo de perfil (entre otros) no sería posible el despliegue de aplicaciones iOS.  ¿Es así?  ¿Si no tengo alguno de esos dispositivos, no puedo subir mis aplicaciones para iOS?

Agradezco me puedan ayudar con ésta inquietud.

A continuación publico algunas imágenes del proceso en cuestión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El dispositivo Apple te sirve para que puedas realizar mejores pruebas de tu app ya que el simulador tiene sus limitaciones.

***No*** necesitas un dispositivo Apple para subir al AppStore; el error es debido a que debes crear Perfiles para Desarrollo y Producción.

Debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

1. Necesitas crear una cuenta de desarrollador en el siguiente link:

   [Developer Apple](https://developer.apple.com)

   El costo para publicar en el AppStore es: $99 (personal) y $199 (empresarial).
2. Debes crear: **Perfiles**, **Identificadores** y **Certificados** en el link anterior e instalar en el Keychain de tu Mac.

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Agregas tu cuenta en Xcode:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. Una vez instalados verificas en el target de tu proyecto de Xcode que accedas a los datos:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5. Seleccionas Cualquier Dispositivo para que ccompile la App:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
6. Archivas la compilación:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
7. Subes la app al AppStore:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez validad y subida al AppStore puedes hacer pruebas con TestFlight, registrar testers y si todo te parece bien envías para que un equipo de Apple revise tu App; si todo es correcto se publica.

Comment: Agradezco tus valiosos aportes.  Pero mi problema está en el 2. de tu numeración: veo que tu PLATFORM es iOS.  Pero cuando trato de crear el Device, antes de asociarlo al respectivo Perfil, y asociarlo al UDID de mi Mac, entonces me aparece mensaje de error, supongo que por ser el ID de una Mac, no de un dispositivo iOS (no sé si pueda agregar imágenes a éste comentario, parece que no).  Así que sigo sin poder avanzar.  De casualidad tú tienes registrado un iOS dentro de tus Devices?  Supongo que sea por eso mi error...........

Comment: No entendí muy bien lo de crear el device. Si puedes unirte al chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224752/ios-profile

Comment: Para quien pueda interesar, y por supuesto con la asesoría de @Bicho, a quien agradezco, el problema se resolvió creando el certificado y perfil de despliegue o Release, ya que al no tener dispositivo iOS físico se presentaban los errores con el certificado / perfil de Desarrollo, que por lo tanto no eran siquiera necesarios.  Después de algunos inconvenientes menores, la generación de la app continuó sin mayores tropiezos